# How to call external javascript file in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, external

I am learning how to call external javascript files in my PHP code. I got some codes from the internet and tried it but its not working. Can somebody pls give me some advice or explain to me this. I am not a programmer but I am studying how to program and just started learning that's why I have difficulty understanding some concepts.

I have here the codes, PHP File and JS file. They are in the same folder.

Here are the codes:

> **index.php**

```
<html>
<head>
 <script language="JavaScript" src="exer_1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="myform">
  <input type="text" id="input_1" name="input_1" /><br />
  <input type="text" id="input_2" name="input_2" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Check!" onclick="javascript:parseTest() return false;" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> **exer_1.js**

```
function parseTest() {
 var elem_1 = document.getElementById('input_1');
 var elem_2 = document.getElementById('input_2');

 var inp_1 = elem_1.value;
 var inp_2 = elem_2.value;

 if (inp_1 == "" && inp_2 == "") {
  alert("You need to enter integers!!!");
  elem_1.focus();
 } else if (inp_1 == ""){
  alert("You need to enter Integer 1!!!");
  elem_1.focus();
 } else if (inp_2 == ""){
  alert("You need to enter Integer 2!!!");
  elem_2.focus();;
 } else {
  if (!parseInt(inp_1) || !parseInt(inp_2)) alert ("Enter Integers only!!!");
  else {
   alert("Correct Inputs!!!");
  }
 } 
}
```

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: as you said you were new to all this, have you ever heard of Firebug plugin for firefox? Its seriously a developers best friend! (If you are using Chrome, it has a similar tool)

Comment: I just forgot the semicolon...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> `<script language="JavaScript" src="exer_1.js"></script>`

The `language` attribute is deprecated, use `type` instead

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="exer_1.js"></script>
```

The correct syntax for inline event binding is

```
<input type="submit" value="Check!" onclick="parseTest(); return false;" />
```

---

You may want to consider moving the event handler to the form's submit event. Your function could then return `false` on error or `true` on success, which can then be used to determine whether the form submission continues or not, eg

```
<form onsubmit="return parseTest()">
```

Comment: Can you pls help me with my code, actually i am using https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4   my code : https://justpaste.it/5ytqq @Phil

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="exer_1.js"></script>
```

Comment: how is it possible to post a blank answer?

Comment: @Ibrahim Check the answer source, it contains HTML

Answer (score 1):

You have not really specified what is not working but i am noticing something in your code.

```
<html>
<head>
 <script language="JavaScript" src="exer_1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <form name="myform">
  <input type="text" id="input_1" name="input_1" /><br />
  <input type="text" id="input_2" name="input_2" /><br />
 <!-- The following will cause an error -->
  <input type="submit" value="Check!" onclick="javascript:parseTest() return false;" />

<!-- instead use this -->
<input type="submit" value="Check!" onclick="javascript:parseTest(); return false;" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

semicolon error

Answer (score 1):

I would look into JQuery for a nice javascript framework. Instead of putting javascript code on the button's "onclick" event, with jquery you could do something like:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
  // whatever code you want to run when submit is clicked.
  alert('Submit clicked');
}
```

Comment: You can do this without jQuery too, it just takes more effort getting it to work cross-browser