# PHP function is not defined error and syntax error of misplaced </p> in generated HTML

Tags: php, javascript, wiki, mediawiki

To solve [a tricky wiki search problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205405/adding-extra-search-text-to-a-mediawiki-search-query-using-inputbox) we've implemented a Javascript solution in a PHP file.

Unfortunately, I have two problems. One is that the function is not being called and secondly I see a syntax error in the Error Console that I cannot solve. First, here is the code within the PHP file:

```
    $htmlOut .=  <<<ENDOFBLOCK
    <script language="javascript">
    function appendAndSubmit(){
    var platform1 = document.getElementById( 'p1').checked;
    var platform2 = document.getElementById( 'p2').checked;
    var text = document.getElementById('search').value;
    if (platform1) text = 'Applies to=Platform 1.0 ' + text;
    if (platform2) text = 'Applies to=Platform 2.0 ' + text;
    alert( text);
    document.getElementById('search').value = text;
    document.forms['searchform'].submit();}
    </script>
    ENDOFBLOCK
    ;
```

So, the first problem is that I see **appendAndSubmit is not defined** in the Error Console.

The second problem is the syntax error. The generated HTML source is:

```
<p><script language="javascript">
function appendAndSubmit(){
var platform1 = document.getElementById( 'p1').checked;
var platform2 = document.getElementById( 'p2').checked;
var text = document.getElementById('search').value;
if (platform1) text = 'Applies to=Platform 1.0 ' + text;
if (platform2) text = 'Applies to=Platform 2.0 ' + text;
alert( text);
document.getElementById('search').value = text;
document.forms['searchform'].submit();}
</p>
</script><div align="center" style="background-color:transparent"><form name="searchbox" id="searchbox" class="searchbox" action="/wiki/index.php?title=Special:Search"><input class="searchboxInput" name="search" type="text" value="" size="50" /><br /><input type="checkbox" name="1" value="&quot;Applies to=Platform 1.0&quot;" id="p1" />&nbsp;<label for="">Platform 1.0</label><input type="checkbox" name="2" value="&quot;Applies to=Platform 2.0&quot;" id="p2" />&nbsp;<label for="">Platform 2.0</label><br /><input type="submit" name="fulltext" class="searchboxSearchButton" value="Go!" onClick="appendAndSubmit();" /></div></form>
```

Note the `</p>` occurs before `</script>`, whereas `<p>` occurs before `<script>`.

Can anyone tell me please what I'm doing wrong?

The call to the appendAndSubmit function is here:

```
    $htmlOut .= Xml::element( 'input',
        array(
            'type' => 'submit',
            'name' => 'fulltext',
            'class' => 'searchboxSearchButton',
            'value' => 'Go!',
            'onClick' => 'appendAndSubmit();'
        )
    );
```

**Complete method:**

```
    public function getSearchPlatform() {

    // Use button label fallbacks
    global $wgContLang;

    // Use button label fallbacks
    if ( !$this->mButtonLabel ) {
        $this->mButtonLabel = wfMsgHtml( 'tryexact' );
    }
    if ( !$this->mSearchButtonLabel ) {
        $this->mSearchButtonLabel = wfMsgHtml( 'searchfulltext' );
    }

    $htmlOut .=  <<<ENDOFBLOCK
<script type="text/javascript">
function appendAndSubmit(){
var platform1 = document.getElementById( 'p1').checked;
var platform2 = document.getElementById( 'p2').checked;
var text = document.getElementById('search').value;
if (platform1) text = 'Applies to=Platform 3.0 ' + text;
if (platform2) text = 'Applies to=Platform 4.0 ' + text;
alert( text);
document.getElementById('search').value = text;
document.forms['searchform'].submit();}
</script>
ENDOFBLOCK
;

    // Build HTML
    $htmlOut .= Xml::openElement( 'div',
        array(
            'align' => 'center',
            'style' => 'background-color:' . $this->mBGColor
        )
    );
    $htmlOut .= Xml::openElement( 'form',
        array(
            'name' => 'searchbox',
            'id' => 'searchbox',
            'class' => 'searchbox',
            'action' => SpecialPage::getTitleFor( 'Search' )->escapeLocalUrl(),
        )
    );
    $htmlOut .= Xml::element( 'input',
        array(
            'class' => 'searchboxInput',
            'name' => 'search',
            'type' => 'text',
            'value' => $this->mDefaultText,
            'size' => $this->mWidth,
        )
    );

    $htmlOut .= $this->mBR;

    // Checkbox
    $htmlOut .= Xml::element( 'input',
        array(
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'name' => '1',
            'value' => '"Applies to=Platform 1.0"',
            'id' => 'p1'
        )
    );
    // Label
    $htmlOut .= '&nbsp;' . Xml::label( 'Platform 2.0' );

    // Checkbox
    $htmlOut .= Xml::element( 'input',
        array(
            'type' => 'checkbox',
            'name' => '2',
            'value' => '"Applies to=Platform 2.0"',
            'id' => 'p2'
        )
    );
    // Label
    $htmlOut .= '&nbsp;' . Xml::label( 'Platform 2.0' );

    // Line break
    $htmlOut .= $this->mBR;

    $htmlOut .= Xml::element( 'input',
        array(
            'type' => 'submit',
            'name' => 'fulltext',
            'class' => 'searchboxSearchButton',
            'value' => 'Go!',
            'onClick' => 'appendAndSubmit();'
        )
    );

    // Hidden fulltext param for IE (bug 17161)
    if( $type == 'fulltext' ) {
        $htmlOut .= Xml::hidden( 'fulltext', 'Search' );
    }

    $htmlOut .= Xml::closeElement( 'div' );
    $htmlOut .= Xml::closeElement( 'form' );

    // Return HTML
    return $htmlOut;
}
```

Comment: What is the syntax error exactly?

Comment: Are you actually outputting the `$htmlOut` variable somewhere? If so, can you please show us where? Also, show us where you're calling the `appendAndSubmit` function.

Comment: @Bono: syntax error: *Note the </p> occurs before </script>, whereas <p> occurs before <script>.* Thanks.

Comment: And how about the generated form control that has the onclick function call?

Comment: And for the syntax error, put the </p> after the </script>. You're basically telling javascript to execute </p>, which is garbage to it. When you nest tags in HTML, you close them in order of last opened to first opened.

Comment: You have an open `<p>` element that you forgot to close or you are outputting the javascript inside the `<p>` element on purpose, and you can't have a `<script>` tag inside a `<p>` tag, close the `<p>` tag first and make sure the script tag is in the root and not inside other elements.

Comment: <script language="javascript"> is deprecated

change to

<script type="text/javascript">

Comment: @BrianWarshaw: thanks, I have added the onclick code.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw: the problem is that I haven't included `<p>` or `</p>` anywhere, but it shows up in the generated code.

Comment: @adeneo: thanks, yes, I get that. But I haven't added the `<p>` `</p>` code, that is automatically generated.

Comment: Please show us where in PHP you are outputting the variable `$htmlOut`.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw: sorry, I thought the `$htmlOut` at the end was enough. After that I have: `$htmlOut .= Xml::closeElement( 'div' );` `$htmlOut .= Xml::closeElement( 'form' );` `return $htmlOut;`

Comment: Ok--two more things: what are you returning `$htmlOut` to (like what is ultimately echoing or printing it), and can you please paste in anywhere that you are assigning to `$htmlOut`? We need to see everything that you're adding to the variable, because somewhere along the line (either in your assignments or in the output processor) `<p>` tags are getting added.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw: thanks for your persistence. I have added the whole function. I am returning the `$htmlOut` to a wiki page [which looks like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205405/adding-extra-search-text-to-a-mediawiki-search-query-using-inputbox).

Comment: How are you returning it to the Wiki page? Do you have the PHP source for the wikipage? I'd like to see what it's doing with your HTML string.

Comment: @BrianWarshaw: I'm really a newbie so don't understand your question. But I'll try: the PHP code (from [InputBox](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:InputBox)) contains a render function which simply contains: `case 'searchPlatform':` `return $this->getSearchPlatform();` The wiki page itself is HTML - I think the relevant part is in the question (CMIIW).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get rid of the `</p>` problem by putting everything between `<script>` and `</script>` on one line. This makes me wonder if it is a problem with the editor (Notepad++ on Windows) when I put the file on the Linux server. But I thought Notepad++ could handle that (it is no problem for PHP).

The fact that the script was not being called was actually due to a syntax error, which I found out via [a clue in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864228/how-to-call-external-javascript-file-in-php): `'search'` should have been `'searchbox'`.

Once that was resolved the function was called without errors.

In case anyone else wants it, here is the complete working code:

```
    public function getSearchPlatform() {

        // Use button label fallbacks
        global $wgContLang;

        // Use button label fallbacks
        if ( !$this->mButtonLabel ) {
            $this->mButtonLabel = wfMsgHtml( 'tryexact' );
        }
        if ( !$this->mSearchButtonLabel ) {
            $this->mSearchButtonLabel = wfMsgHtml( 'searchfulltext' );
        }

        $htmlOut .=  <<<ENDOFBLOCK
        <script type="text/javascript">function appendAndSubmit(){var platform1 = document.getElementById('p1').checked;var platform2 = document.getElementById('p2').checked;var text = document.getElementById('searchboxInput').value;if (platform1 * platform2 >0) text = text + ' "Applies to=Platform 1.0" "Applies to=Platform 2.0"';else if (platform1) text = text + ' "Applies to=Platform 1.0"';else if (platform2) text = text + ' "Applies to=Platform 2.0"';document.getElementById('searchboxInput').value = text;document.forms['searchform'].submit();}</script>
ENDOFBLOCK;

        // Build HTML
        $htmlOut .= Xml::openElement( 'div',
            array(
                'align' => 'center',
                'style' => 'background-color:' . $this->mBGColor
            )
        );
        $htmlOut .= Xml::openElement( 'form',
            array(
                'name' => 'searchbox',
                'id' => 'searchbox',
                'class' => 'searchbox',
                'action' => SpecialPage::getTitleFor( 'Search' )->escapeLocalUrl(),
            )
        );
        $htmlOut .= Xml::element( 'input',
            array(
                'class' => 'searchboxInput',
                'name' => 'search',
                'id' => 'searchboxInput',
                'type' => 'text',
                'value' => $this->mDefaultText,
                'size' => $this->mWidth,
            )
        );

        $htmlOut .= $this->mBR;

        // Checkbox
        $htmlOut .= Xml::element( 'input',
            array(
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => '1',
                'id' => 'p1'
            )
        );
        // Label
        $htmlOut .= '&nbsp;' . Xml::label( 'Platform 1.0' );

        // Checkbox
        $htmlOut .= Xml::element( 'input',
            array(
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => '2',
                'id' => 'p2'
            )
        );
        // Label
        $htmlOut .= '&nbsp;' . Xml::label( 'Platform 2.0' );

        // Line break
        $htmlOut .= $this->mBR;

        $htmlOut .= Xml::element( 'input',
            array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'name' => 'fulltext',
                'class' => 'searchboxSearchButton',
                'value' => 'search',
                'onClick' => "appendAndSubmit();"
            )
        );

        // Hidden fulltext param for IE (bug 17161)
        if( $type == 'fulltext' ) {
            $htmlOut .= Xml::hidden( 'fulltext', 'Search' );
        }

        $htmlOut .= Xml::closeElement( 'div' );
        $htmlOut .= Xml::closeElement( 'form' );

        // Return HTML
        return $htmlOut;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the issue with the misplaced `<p>` tag inside the `<script>` element. It is possible that your syntax error within those `<script>` tags is preventing the registration of the function, since it is declared in that same block.

**UPDATE**
So it's hard to say, because ultimately the Wiki engine is what's probably calling `render()` on `InputBox`. But here's a suggestion that may help. For most of your elements, you're adding them with static methods from the `Xml` class. Have you tried creating your `script` tag with `Xml::openElement`? Then you can put your heredoc declaration of the script's body between those calls. If something is inserting `p` tags arbitrarily on the Wiki side, perhaps using this method will output it in such a way that this doesn't end up happening. It's worth a shot, because, honestly, I can't see anything in the code you've posted that indicates that paragraph tags should be inserted from your code here.

Comment: I wish I could. That's my question - I don't know why the generated code puts the `<p>` (or rather the `</p>`) in the wrong place.

Comment: See my most recent comment on the actual question--show us where you're outputting that variable with the script in it, and that should help.

Comment: Thanks for the **update**. I think this is a bit beyond my (I'm still a newbie). I'll try to put the JS in a different file first, and use this as a backup plan.

Comment: FWIW, it happens when I remove all the code except: `$htmlOut .=  <<<ENDOFBLOCK
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
ENDOFBLOCK
;`!

Comment: I managed to get rid of the `</p>` problem by putting everything between `<script>` and `</script>` on one line. This makes me wonder if it is a problem with the editor (Notepad++ on Windows) when I put the file on the Linux server. But I thought Notepad++ could handle that (it is no problem for PHP). Now to tackle the fact that the function is not being called...

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem with the function not being called to this line: `var text = document.getElementById('search').value;` will pick it up again later.

Comment: That was easily fixed: `'search'` should have been `'searchbox'`!

Comment: Thanks for your help Brian - I have now solved it. (I couldn't upvote this answer, but have upvoted you elsewhere!)

Comment: Awesome, so glad you got it fixed. I would still love to know why you got the extra paragraph tag! Notepad++ shouldn't be the culprit, as it's just a raw text editor and doesn't do anything funky like that. At any rate, good luck, and happy continued coding!